# When I try to start sensu service it fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sensu

When I try to start my sensu service it fails and I get the following error in the log. It was working before and then when I did a restart I continued to get the following error. I am not sure how to debug it. Appreciate any help in the right direction.

> C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:859:in
>   `open_udp_socket': no datagram socket (RuntimeError)  from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:859:in`
>   open_datagram_socket'    from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-0.12.6/lib/sensu/client.rb:257:in
>   `setup_sockets'   from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-0.12.6/lib/sensu/client.rb:293:in`
>   start'   from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-0.12.6/lib/sensu/client.rb:13:in
>   `block in run'    from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in`
>   call'    from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in
>   `run_machine'     from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in`
>   run'     from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-0.12.6/lib/sensu/client.rb:12:in
>   `run'     from
>   C:/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sensu-0.12.6/bin/sensu-client:10:in`
>   '    from C:/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/sensu-client:23:in
>   `load'    from C:/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/sensu-client:23:in`'

Comment: It looks like something is already using the socket that this program wants to use.  Typically this could mean that it is already running.

Comment: When you run `sudo service sensu-client restart` it returns showed error, right?

Comment: @AlexanderKarmes This is from a windows machine.

Comment: @JohnC do you know how I can test what other services might be running on this socket?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of Windows version do you have but `netstat -a -n -o` does the job on most of versions.